# Changing color of UI Text in Unity into custom values

Tags: c#, unity, gui

There are a few objects in the scene as well as a title. I want the title to change its text and color based on the object that is mouse-overed. The script below is added to each object that is intended to change the color and text of the title.

The title changes it's color correctly when values like `Color.red` are assigned but doesn't change color when values like `new Color(254f, 152f, 203f)`.

```
public Text title;

void OnMouseEnter()
{
    switch(name)
    {
    CONDITION1:
        title.color = Color.yellow;  // works well
        break;

    CONDITION2:
        title.color = new Color(254f, 152f, 203f);  // doesn't work
        break;
    }

    title.text = name;
}

void OnMouseExit()
{
    title.text = "DEFAULT VALUE";
    title.color = Color.white;
}
```

Is there a specific reason to the former method to work and latter not to work? How can I change the color of the `Text` element with custom values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructor of Color class takes float parameters from 0 to 1 like this `title.color = new Color(1f, 0.5f, 0.8f);`

Comment: oh god... I don't know the reason behind me assuming the constructor took float values ranged from 0 to 255. It doesn't even make sense! I think I am too tired at this moment:)

Comment: This is the same answer all around. The thing is my "Title" is a GameObject>Canvas>UIText. The GameObjects has Text embeded into it. It seemed the only way to get my text to be able to set dynamically onto a grid. Or should I not do this? All the youtube tutorials put Text into a GameObject. So when I try to change it, it breaks runtime.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with the code below:

```
title.color = new Color(254.0f/255.0f, 152.0f/255.0f, 203.0f/255.0f);
```

Comment: This should be accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to pass RGBA in the common way you can also use Color32 that takes 4 bytes ranged from 0 - 255:

```
title.color = new Color32(254, 152, 203, 255);
```